# how to use array data from php in javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

I don't know if I'll be able to explain this correctly to you. But I hope you guys will understand what I want. First, I'm using this library [spin wheel][1]

I'm using php that will insert data which is the stopAt angle. Then I fetch those data to able to use them.

This is my select code:

```
$newQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `anglefive` where user_name='".$user."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newQuery)) {
    if($row){
         
    $res= $row['stopAt'];
        echo json_encode($res); 

    }
    
    
}
```

The result looks like this

```
265 292 350 190 320
```

Now I want to use these five values in my js code

This is my js code in another file

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'dataFive.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : data,
        success : function (result) {
            
             
            theWheel.animation.stopAngle= result;
            theWheel.startAnimation();

             wheelSpinning = true;
        },
        error : function () {
           alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Now what I want is to use the 5 value from php in my JS code so the wheel will run 5 times and in each time it will stop at one of the 5 result from first to last (265 292 350 190 320)

the code should go here because this specify the stopAngle: `theWheel.animation.stopAngle= result;`

Also the five value won't be the same every time.

Hope you understood what I want. I've been stuck here and I really need help
[1]: http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/docs

Comment: First step will be to encode the data in a JSON array so it comes in a structured way back to the Javascript. See the json_encode() function in PHP. Then in JS use the first value from the array to the animation, and use the next value when the animation stops

Comment: @ADyson but i want to use all five because at each spin it will generate a prize. so i want five prizes at the end

Comment: @ADyson when i used json_encode() the php result looks like this :"265""292""350""190""320"  and when i push it to JS array the result is like this :["\"230\"\"100\"\"265\"\"320\"\"292\"\r\n"]

Comment: `the php result looks like this`...no it doesn't because that isn't valid JSON. I'm guessing maybe you encoded each value separately or something (instead of making a PHP array and then encoding the array)? Please update your question to show precisely what you tried with json_encode then we can fix it for you.

Comment: @ADyson this is what I added `echo json_encode($res)`

Comment: Yeah so like I said, that isn't right. Because you're running that multiple times inside a loop, It produces lots of individual JSON items, not a single, coherent object or array. You need to create one piece of JSON containing all the data, not lots of separate pieces. Create a PHP array. Add $res to the array each time you loop. When the loop ends, encode the whole array as JSON in one command, and echo it.

Comment: @ADyson i tried it this way ` while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newQuery)) {
 if($row){
   
     $res= $row['stopAt'];
  
  
$new=array($res); 
 }
 
 echo json_encode($new); 
 
}` and the result is like this ["350"]["230"]["190"]["292"]["265"]

Comment: Did you read the bit where I said you need to encode it **when the loop ends**? And also you need to make _one_ array, not make a new array each time you loop. Make the array _before_ the loop. Then push to the array inside the loop, then encode the array after the loop.

Comment: P.S. `if($row)` is redundant - if there are no rows left the loop simply won't run again anyway.

Comment: So... `$arr = array(); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newQuery)) { $arr[] = $row['stopAt']; } echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: @ADyson I actually tried it this way but I added the array creation in the loop and not before. Anyway, Thank you so much it worked